# I got more flags/day. Is that because of the Marshal badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, flags

I just flagged my first answer after I got the Marshal badge, and I noticed that I have 62 flags remaining. This number is higher then I got previously, iirc. Is this because I got the Marshal badge and now am 'trusted'?

(and yes, part of this question is just me being happy about my third gold badge here :))

Comment: You get more flags/day based on validated flags. You just noticed it now with the marshal badge (I think you even only start out with 10 flags/day)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

> When you start out, you are allotted 10 flags per day. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day:
>
> - You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation.
> - You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).